# ¿Como acceder a campo JSON con punto?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este JSON

`[{"usr_pres.name":"xxx","emp":"001"}]` que me devuelve una función Ajax.

Siempre he accedido a cada elemento de  esta forma:

```
success: function (data) {
            objJsonPT = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(objJsonPT['0'].emp);
```

Si accedo al valor de `emp`, lo devuelve bien pero si accedo al valor de usr_pres.name me da error, dice que name no está definido. Creo que tiene que ver con el `"."`

Sin embargo cuando le hago un `console.log(data)` si veo bien los datos tal y como los muestro.

```
[{"usr_pres.name":"xxx","emp":"001"}]
```

Lo que me gustaría sería poder acceder al valor de `usr_pres.name` que seria: "xxx"

Gracias

Comment: Probaste `objJsonPT['0']['usr_pres.name']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hazlo mediante el uso de corchetes:

```
objJsonPT[0]["usr_pres.name"];
```

Esta es la manera correcta de acceder al valor de JSON cuyo nombre incluye un punto.

Un saludo!