# Problema con datatable column y valor de json

Tags: json, datatables

Mi intención es alimentar una tabla de datatables con  el json.
Tengo una función en la que uso el framework datatables, hasta ahora lo había usado muchas veces pero ahora me he encontrado que cuando quiero alimentar la tabla con el siguiente json me da le siguiente error.

```
DataTables warning: table id=tbl_Pedidos - Requested unknown parameter 'proy_sim.name' for row 0, column 5. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

El framework es de jquery
En el apartado column de datatables, si el valor del json con la que alimento la datatable  lleva un punto me da el error que he puesto arriba

Tengo este Json :

```
{

    "prsp_sol": [
        {
            "proy_sim.name": "Vehículos",
            "prsp_def.name": "TRACTOR",
            "cnt": 2613,
        }
    ]
}
```

y mi columna de datatable es la siguiente:

```
"columns": [
                    {"data": "proy_sim.name"}, 
                    {"data": "prsp_def.name"}, 
                    {"data": "cnt"}, 

            ]
```

El problema viene cuando el valor del  json tiene un campo con un punto. loquesea.loquesea, he probado con corchetes. Si el campo no tiene un punto, funciona bien.

```
 {"data": "proy_sim[name"]},
```

Pero no funciona.

Comment: No funciona...¿El que? Te da algún error en concreto? Y ¿Qué es lo que tratas de hacer?

Comment: ufffff, voy a editar mi pregunta

Comment: Ya si pones el lenguaje que estas usando genial XD (aunque entiendo que es un framework de JQuery). De todas formas mírate esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259307/como-acceder-a-campo-json-con-punto/259309#259309) y prueba a cambiar la forma en la que accedes al campo

Comment: Buenas, esa pregunta la hice yo hace poco y para acceder al campo me fue bien, en este caso hablamos de una columna de datatable y no me funciona. Gracias.

Comment: Ups, fallo mío. Que pasa si intentas escapar el punto? Osease cambiar `"proy_sim.name"` por `"proy_sim\.name"`

Comment: No ha  hay manera, lo he hecho como me lo ha dicho  pero datatable da el mismo error y no aparece ese campo, si los demás

Comment: Mi última bala es esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691507/datatables-columns-with-dot-in-header-not-displaying-correctly) de SO. Prueba a añadir estas funciones.

Comment: He tomado la idea de tu último comentario, he conseguido recorrer el lrigen de datos y cambiar el "." por un "_" y me ha funcionado. Gracias.

Comment: Pon tu comentario como respuesta que la pueda valorar

Answer (score 0):

Este framework no admite un string con punto como header de una columna, por lo que la mejor solución es "sanear" estos datos como indican en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691507/datatables-columns-with-dot-in-header-not-displaying-correctly) de SO.

Añado el código de la respuesta en ingles para la perpetuidad.

```
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4z5xd', function(json) {
    //remove whitespace and dots from keys / attribute names    
    function sanitizeData(jsonArray) {
        var newKey;
        jsonArray.forEach(function(item) {
            for (key in item) {
                newKey = key.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\./g, '');
                if (key != newKey) {
                    item[newKey]=item[key];
                    delete item[key];
                }     
            }    
        })    
        return jsonArray;
    }            
    //remove whitespace and dots from data : <propName> references
    function sanitizeColumns(jsonArray) {
        var dataProp;
        jsonArray.forEach(function(item) {
            dataProp = item['data'].replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\./g, '');
            item['data'] = dataProp;
        })
        return jsonArray;
    }    
    json.data = sanitizeData(json.data);
    json.columns = sanitizeColumns(json.columns);    

    $('#example').DataTable({
       data : json.data,
       columns : json.columns
    })
});
```

No olvidar dar el voto a la respuesta en inglés si ha funcionado, pues el mérito es suyo.

Un saludo!